# Heat Equation with One Non-Homogeneous Boundary Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I posed myself the following PDE because it would be interesting to graph:
$$
u_t=u_{xx},\qquad0<x<L,\qquad t>0,\\
\begin{align}
u(0,t)&=\sin^2\frac t2,\\
u_x(L,t)&=0,\\
u(x,0)&=0.
\end{align}$$
Physically, this is a rod with one end insulated and the other being periodically heated and cooled.

Now, since the $x$-dependent problem does not have two homogeneous boundary conditions, I wonder if it is possible to solve this PDE as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I was taught to solve boundary value problems with non-homogeneous boundary value conditions is via the introduction of a second term to satisfy the boundary, i.e. set
$$ u(x,t) = \phi(x,t) + v(x,t)$$
where $\phi(x,t)$ satisfies the boundary conditions.

So, we need
$$\phi_x(0,t)=0 \text{ and }\phi(L,t)=\sin^2\frac{t}{2}.$$
The simplest function that satisfies these conditions is
$$\phi(x,t)=\sin^2\frac{t}{2},$$
which means $u$ is of the form
$$u(x,t)=\sin^2\frac{t}{2}+v(x,t).$$

The pde now required to solve, for $v$ after substituting into your equation is
$$v_t=v_{xx}-\cos\frac{t}{2}.$$
Substituting into the boundary conditions also gives
$$v_x(0,t)=0\text{ and } v(L,t)=0$$
and the initial condition condition
$$v(x,0)=0.$$

This transforms the original problem with non-homogeneous boundary conditions into one with homogeneous boundary conditions, but a non-homogeneous pde, which is easier to solve.

Can you continue from this point?

Comment: Yes, I can continue from here on. Thank you very much for your help! I had not heard of that technique before. :)

Comment: In fact your approach is similar to that in http://maths.swan.ac.uk/staff/vl/pdes-course.pdf#page=38.

Comment: Is there a general formula for finding φ(x,t) in case of more difficult problems?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/261255/52893) is a different approach, called the *method of eigenfunction expansions*.

Answer (score -1):

I correct your differentiation mistake,

$$(\sin^2(\frac{t}{2}))' = 2\sin(\frac{t}{2})(\frac{1}{2})\cos(\frac{t}{2}) = \sin(\frac{t}{2})\cos(\frac{t}{2}).$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).