# How do the solutions of a heat equation with time-dependent boundary conditions behave at the end points?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Assume that $u(x,t)$ solves the heat equation:

\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t) = u_{xx}(x,t),\hspace{1cm} (0<x<L)
\end{equation}

subject to the time-dependent boundary conditions:

\begin{equation}
u(0,t)=0, \\ u(L,t)=g(t).
\end{equation}

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261251/heat-equation-with-time-dependent-boundary-conditions) user JohnD has solved it by assuming the *eigenfunction expansion* form:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x)}e^{-\lambda_n t},
\end{equation}

and then proceeds to find the coefficients $b_n$.

Also There is a slightly different approach introduced in this [page](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Heat_equation/Solution_to_the_1-D_Heat_Equation). At first the solution is written as the sum of two functions:

$$u(x,t)=s(x,t) + v(x,t),$$ 
$s(x,t)$ is the part that satisfies the nonhomogeneous boundary conditions, which for the problem at hand becomes:
$$ s(x,t) = \frac{x}{L} g(t),$$
and then $v(x,t)$ satisfies the following equation:
$$v_t (x,t) - v_{xx} (x,t) = - s_t(x,t), \hspace{1cm} v(0,t)=v(L,t)=0$$
Again the solution proceeds by expanding both sides of the equation in terms of the eigenfunctions of LHS, i.e. :
$$\sin(n\pi \frac{x}{L}),$$

(this method is also explained [here](http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/fall03/m4354_f03/heat_nonhomo_D.pdf) and [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261251/heat-equation-with-time-dependent-boundary-conditions)).

**Questions:**

**1.**
In the [first method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261251/heat-equation-with-time-dependent-boundary-conditions) mentioned above, the obtained solution doesn't meet the required boundary conditions:

$$ u(L,t) =g(t),$$
because $\sin(n \pi)$ is always zero, and so regardless of the value of $b_n$s, we always get $u(L,t)=0.$
Is that right or am I missing sth obvious? (for eg. maybe the limit of the obtained solution when $x$ approaches $L$ is $g(t)$, but I couldn't check this limit)
Is the obtained result by this method *a solution* of the boundary value PDE?

**2.**
Regarding the [second method](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281997/solution-methods-for-heat-equation-with-time-dependent-boundary-conditions), is expanding a linear function ( i.e. $\frac{x}{L} g(t)$) in terms of $\sin(n \pi \frac{x}{L})$s legitimate? because again regardless of their coefficients, they give $0$ for $x=L$.

**3.**
As a consequence of #2, the obtained solution by using the second method doesn't satisfy the original PDE  *exactly at $x=L$*, because on the one hand:
$$u_t(L,t) = s_t(L,t) + v_t(L,t) = g_t(t),$$
and on the other hand:
$$u_{xx}(L,t) = s_{xx}(L,t) + v_{xx}(L,t) = 0$$

the question is just like #1: Is the obtained result by this method *a solution* of the boundary value PDE?

**4.**
Can we solve this PDE on the domain $[0,L]$, instead of $(0,L)$?