# Diffusion equation with time-dependent boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

The bottom surface (located at $y=0$) of a semi-infinite, electrically conducting slab is subject to the slowly oscillating magnetic field $B = B_0 \cos(\omega t)$.

I am trying to find an expression for the magnetic field within the conductor as a function of $y$ and $t$ using the 1D diffusion equation:
$$\frac{\partial B}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial y^2}$$

I know that the solution is given by:
$$B = B_0 \exp(-\frac{y}{\delta})\cos(\omega t -\frac{y}{\delta})$$
where $\delta = \sqrt{2 \alpha/\omega}$.

However, I can't quite figure out how to get there due to the time-dependent boundary condition.

I have tried separation of variables but with not much luck, since the solution I am looking for can't be expressed as a product $Y(y)T(t)$.

Could someone please tell me how to get to the solution?

Comment: The solution you're looking at points to the initial state of the medium being $B(0, y) = B_0e^{-y/\delta}\cos(y/\delta)$. This seems pretty specific. Are there other assumptions about the physics?

Comment: @Aruralreader Nope, no other assumptions given in the question unfortunately

Comment: From a physical point of view I find it odd that a magnetic field obeys a heat equation. Anyway. Are you sure the solution $
B=B_0\,e^{-\frac{y}{\delta}}\cos(\omega t-\frac{y}{\delta})$ solves the equation? [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/261255/949989) might be very useful.

Comment: @KurtG. Yep, it does satisfy $B_t - \alpha B_{yy} = 0$ and the condition at $y=0$.

Comment: @Aruralreader, I checked that too. Then what is OP's question about?

Comment: @KurtG. My question is about how to show/prove the form of the solution, rather than just verifying that it is a solution.

Comment: @KurtG. My understanding is that the OP is interested in seeing the methodology used for constructing this solution.

Comment: On the general methodology for this type of problem I provided a link in my comment above.

Comment: @KurtG. I looked at the methodology, but it seems to be restricted to cases where $y$ is bounded between 0 and some finite $l$. My boundary conditions here are $B(0,t)$ and $B(\infty, t)$, which leaves me unsure on how to use separation of variables to find a solution to the case with homogeneous BCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slight changes in notation, we look for bounded solutions of $B_t = \alpha B_{yy}$ in the
half-plane $y>0$ subject to $B(t, y=0) = B_0\cos\omega_0 t$.

Suppose $B$ is a solution. Proceeding formally, assume
\begin{equation*}
 B(t, y) =
 \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty c(\omega, y)\cos\omega t\, d\omega + 
 \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty s(\omega, y)\sin\omega t\, d\omega
 \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
 c(\omega, y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\, B(t, y)\cos\omega t\, dt, \\
 s(\omega, y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\, B(t, y)\sin\omega t\, dt
\end{align*}
are the Fourier cosine and sine transforms of $B(t, y)$ with respect to $t$.
If $B$ satisfies $B_t = \alpha B_{yy}$ then substitution into (1) and rearrangement
shows these transforms must be related as
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
     -\omega c(\omega, y) &= \alpha s_{yy}(\omega, y), \\
    \omega s(\omega, y) &= \alpha c_{yy}(\omega, y).
    \end{aligned}
 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Computing $c_{yyyy}$ and $s_{yyyy}$ we see that $c$ and $s$ satisfying this system
also satisfy $c_{yyyy} + (\omega/\alpha)^2 c = 0$ and $s_{yyyy} + (\omega/\alpha)^2 s = 0$.
Each has four linearly independent solutions
\begin{align*}
 & \exp(-\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\cos(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y), \\
 & \exp(-\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\sin(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y), \\
 & \exp(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\cos(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y), \\
 & \exp(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\sin(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y).
\end{align*}
The third and fourth forms are unbounded as $y\rightarrow\infty$ so we ignore them
and make use of the first and second only:
\begin{equation*}
 c(\omega, y) = \exp(-\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\biggl(c_1(\omega)\cos(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)
 + c_2(\omega)\sin(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\biggr),
\end{equation*}
and similarly
\begin{equation*}
 s(\omega, y) = \exp(-\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\biggl(s_1(\omega)\cos(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)
 + s_2(\omega)\sin(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\biggr).
\end{equation*}
Note that (2) implies a relation between $c_1, c_2$ and $s_1, s_2$,
specifically $s_1(\omega) = - c_2(\omega)$, $s_2(\omega) = c_1(\omega)$.

With these results, at $y = 0$ we have
\begin{align*}
 B(t, 0) &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\, c(\omega, 0)\,\cos\omega t\, d\omega + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\, s(\omega, 0)\,\sin\omega t\, d\omega \\
 &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\,c_1(\omega)\cos\omega t \, d\omega
 + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\,s_1(\omega)\sin\omega t \, d\omega.
\end{align*}
The condition $B(t, 0) = B_0\cos\omega_0 t$ suggests $c_1(\omega) = \pi B_0\delta(\omega - \omega_0)$
and $s_1(\omega) = 0$. Thus $c_2(\omega) = 0$, $s_2(\omega) = \pi B_0\delta(\omega - \omega_0)$. So
\begin{align*}
 c(\omega, y) &= \pi B_0\exp(-\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\cos(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\delta(\omega - \omega_0) \\
 s(\omega, y) &= \pi B_0\exp(-\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\sin(\sqrt{\omega/2\alpha}y)\delta(\omega - \omega_0).
\end{align*}
Substitution into (1) and a bit of algebra gives
\begin{equation*}
 B(t, y) = B_0\exp(-\sqrt{\omega_0/2\alpha}y) \cos(\sqrt{\omega_0/2\alpha}y - \omega_0 t).
\end{equation*}

**Addendum in hindsight**

The above approach works for a large class of driving functions at $y = 0$, however, with $B_0\cos\omega_0 t$, things are far simpler. From a physics perspective you might argue the driver is $\omega_0$-periodic, so look for $\omega_0$-periodic solutions. That is:

$$B(t, y) = u(y)\cos\omega_0 t + v(y)\sin\omega_0 t.$$

Working with this form to begin with gets you to the same result with a lot less pain, and maybe a bit of physical-reasoning satisfaction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This looks really promising. Might I ask why we assume that $B(y,t)$ takes the form given in (1)?

Comment: @VJ123. It's simply the real form of the (inverse) Fourier transform, so you're starting with a rather broad basis.

Comment: Ah I see, so we're essentially saying that $B(y,t)$ is equal to the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of $B(y,t)$ if I understand correctly?

Comment: @VJ123. Yes, that’s the case.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes a lot more sense. Thank you also for your edit, which was very helpful. I'll have another read through this tomorrow (getting pretty late where I am!) and then accept the solution. One final question, you say "The above approach works for a large class of driving functions at $y=0$" - does this method have any particular name?

Comment: @VJ123. Fourier analysis.

Comment: Perfect! I've spent far too long trying to figure this out, so really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @VJ123: Too long? Not a single moment working through a problem in mathematics is wasted. Be patient and persistent.